# Returning a reference to a variable: Meaningful/useful?

Tags: c++, function, reference, return-value, assignment-operator

Say you have the following code:

```
MyObject someObject;

MyObject& getReferenceToObject() {
    return someObject;
}
```

Now consider the following to ways to call `getReferenceToObject()`:

```
void MyFunction() {
    MyObject obj = getReferenceToObject(); // 1.
    MyObject& obj = getReferenceToObject(); // 2.
}
```

The compiler allows both 1. and 2. My question is, if I do it like 1., will the Object be copied into the `obj` variable, or will `obj` point to `someObject`? And does 2. make any sense at all?

Comment: 1. copy 2. yes.

Comment: thanks very much :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Version 1. Initialises a MyObject, called `obj` with the `MyObject::MyObject(const MyObject & other);` constructor (or similar). `obj` is a copy of `someObject`

Version 2. Initialises a reference to MyObject, (also) called obj, so that it names the same object as `someObject`.

If you mutate `obj`, version 1 will not change `someObject`, version 2 will.

Comment: 5 more minutes to go :(

Answer (score 1):

That depends on scope of someObject. First one will just copy the whole object. But if you are planning to use it in second way, someObject should be either global object or static object. Because once you return from getReferenceToObject(), the stack is gone and you can't access local object defined inside the function. So returning local object as reference won't work.

Comment: Oh I was a little bit unclear here, `someObject` is not intented to be a local variable but rather a global/static variable or a class member (if `getReferenceToObject` were a class method :D) as you suggested.

Comment: Exactly tagelicht